# Controlling the stereo output levels separately from overall volume level

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I don't know why, but to get my right loudspeaker sounding equally loud as the left one, I have to set the levels in `alsamixer` like so:

http://s18.postimg.org/91nx9ojex/alsa.png

54/100 in Headphones column.

It is inconvenient for me, because when I habitually try to control overall sound level by Fn+Up/Down, it resets the left/right levels balance. So is there any way to permanently set stereo levels separately in some alsa/pulseaudio configuration files or utilities?

Comment: Speakers are not headphones. Are your speakers connected correctly? Try re-plugging them.

Comment: My laptop has only one external audio output, for both speakers and headphones. Since it's an ordinary audio jack, I don't think it's smart enough to determine what's connected to it. So laptop simply labels it as "Headphones". I tried replugging many times, no effect.